# How to use values in list from one function in a second function

Tags: python

I am working on coding a precalculous problem.  I was able to write one function and get an (x,y) plot in a python list.  I want to be able to call list[0] and list[1] of the first function in a second function. How do I setup my functions so that I can use the outputs from the first function as inputs in the second functions?

```
import numpy as np
import sympy as sy

# find the point of intersection of two points by using a linear function

def intersection(slope1, yintercept1, slope2, yintercept2):
    xval = -1*slope1+slope2
    recip = np.reciprocal(xval)
    xval = yintercept1*recip
    yval = slope2*xval
    point = [xval, yval]
    return point
print(intersection((sy.Rational(-6,7)), 9, sy.Rational(7,6), 0))

#find the distance two points are apart.

def distance(x, y):

#I want to call the point from my intersection function here and put them into the distance formula 
to find out how far away the point is from the origin.  
 
print(distance(0,0))
```

Comment: If your function `distance()` finds the distance between **two** points, then surely its signature should be `distance(x1, y1, x2, y2)`?

Comment: You can use declare points list as globally so it is accessible to both functions.

Comment: return `point` as a `tuple` and unpack it in your call to `distance`.

Answer (score 0):

Your function intersection is returning a list, so you save that into a variable, then you call the distance function with this variable that you got from intersection

```
import math #for numeric sqrt you import math

def distance(p):
    x=p[0]
    y=p[1]
    return math.sqrt(x**2 + y**2) # euclidian distance to (0,0)

point = intersection((sy.Rational(-6,7)), 9, sy.Rational(7,6), 0))
d = distance(point)
```

Comment: This is not an optimal solution. The python `*` operator exists so you specifically don't have to manually unpack the data. At the absolute least it should be `x, y = p` with `p` as a  `tuple`. But it really should be leaving `x` and `y` as `distance`s arguments and calling it like this `distance(*point)`.

Comment: I know, but it's clear the person is very new to programming, so I just used the basics, and redefined the distance function

Answer (score 0):

I found my problem.  I was printing my function after I was finished running it and I needed to save the value of the function into a variable.  Once I saved it to a new variable then I could use that variable in the next function.  Now I am having a problem dealing with rational numbers and taking the square root using sympy.

```
from numpy import reciprocal, sqrt
from sympy import Rational

'''Find the area of a right triangle by finding a point
where two perpendicular lines intersect, and by finding the distance
the point is away from the origin'''

# Enter the slope and y intercept for each of the perpendicular lines.  

slope_line_one = Rational(-6,7)
y_intercept_line_one = 9
slope_line_two = Rational(7,6)
y_intercept_line_two = 0
perpendicular_lines = [slope_line_one, y_intercept_line_one, slope_line_two, 
y_intercept_line_two]

# A function to find the (x,y) value where two perpendicular points intersect

def intersection(slope_one, y_intercept_one, slope_two, y_intercept_two):
    xval = -1*slope_one+slope_two
    recip = reciprocal(xval)
    xval = y_intercept_one*recip
    yval = slope_two*xval
    point = [xval, yval]
    return point
point_of_intersection = (intersection(perpendicular_lines[0], perpendicular_lines[1], 
perpendicular_lines[2], perpendicular_lines[3]))
print(point_of_intersection)

# This function is to find how far away the point made by the perpendicular lines is 
from the origin
origin = [0, 0]
def distance(x_two, x_one, y_two, y_one):
    xdistance = (x_two-x_one)**2
    return xdistance
length_leg_one = (distance(origin[0], point_of_intersection[0], origin[1], 
point_of_intersection[1]))
print(length_leg_one)
```